# what is the url to get the number of friends a user has by user ID by graph api or FQL

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi this is my piece of code to get the number of friends a user has by python . It returns nothing. Can anyone tell me which access privilege should i grant or anything wrong what i have done so far?

```
friend_count = 0
q = urllib.urlencode({'SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid': 784877761})

url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=' + q

request = urllib2.Request(url)
data = urllib2.urlopen(request)
doc = parse(data)


friend_count_node = doc.getElementsByTagName("friend_count")
test = friend_count_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue
logging.info(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
q = urllib.urlencode({'SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = 784877761'})

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' + q
```

You should not need an access token to get the `friend_count`.